# Let $R$ be a ring and $u$ be an element that has two right inverses, show that it has infinite right inverses (Kaplansky's problem).

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am self studying ring theory and found this problem:

> Let $R$ be a ring and $u$ be an element that has two right inverses, show that it has infinite right inverses.

I have worked out the following proof, but I am not really convinced in some steps and the proofs that I have seen are different, I would appreciate if someone could comment on it.

Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct right inverses of $u$. That is $ux=1$ and $uy=1$

With the notation $nx$ denoting the sum of $x$ $n$ times we have the following:

$u(nx-(n-1)y)=unx-u(n-1)y=n(ux)-(n-1)(uy)=n-n-1=1$

Now we show that for $k\neq n$, $nx-(n-1)y \neq kx-(k-1)y$

Suppose that $nx-(n-1)y = kx-(k-1)y$ and with loss of generality that $k<n$, then

$(n-k)x=(n-k)y$  which implies that $x=y$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why does $(n-k)x=(n-k)y$ imply that $x=y$? For example, in the ring $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, $(3-1)(0+2\Bbb Z) = (3-1)(1+2\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Where in Kaplansky? I have all of his books; he gave me copies

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you very much, I see the problem